# Find the fundamental solution

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the fundamental solutions of the following differential operators. Check that they satisfy (outside the singularity) the homogeneous equation in principal variables and the conjugate equation in dual variables
> $$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}+2\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y\partial t}+2\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial z\partial t}-2\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y\partial z}$$

**My attempt:**

Suppose the solution can be written in the form

$$u(t, x, y, z) = e^{i\omega t}e^{ikx}e^{(m+in)y}e^{(p+q)z},$$

where $\omega$, $k$, $m$, $n$, $p$ and $q$ are arbitrary real numbers.

$$\left(\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}+2\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y\partial t}+2\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial z\partial t}-2\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y\partial z}\right)u(t, x, y, z) = 0$$

$$(-\omega^2 + k^2 + 2i\omega m - 2m^2 - 2n^2 - 2p^2 + 2i\omega q - 2q^2)e^{i\omega t}e^{ikx}e^{(m+in)y}e^{(p+q)z} = 0$$

We can now analyse each of the multipliers to determine the values of the parameters $\omega$, $k$, $m$, $n$, $p$ and $q$

1. The multiplier $e^{i\omega t}$ is zero when $\omega = 0$.
2. The multiplier $e^{ikx}$ is zero when $k = 0$.
3. The multiplier $e^{(m+in)y}$ is zero when $m = n = 0$.
4. The multiplier $e^{(p+q)z}$ is zero when $p = q = 0$.

Getting the fundamentals right

$$u(t, x, y, z) = e^{(0+0i)t}e^{(0+0i)x}e^{(0+0i)y}e^{(0+0i)z} = 1$$

The homogeneous equation in principal variables is

$$\left(\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}+2\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y\partial t}+2\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial z\partial t}-2\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y\partial z}\right)u(t, x, y, z) = 0$$

$$u(t, x, y, z) = 1\Rightarrow \left(\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}+2\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y\partial t}+2\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial z\partial t}-2\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y\partial z}\right)1 = 0$$

Now consider the conjugate equation in dual variables

$$\left(-\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial t^2}+\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}+2\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y\partial t}+2\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial z\partial t}-2\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y\partial z}\right)\tilde{u}(t, x, y, z) = 0,$$

where $\tilde{u}(t, x, y, z)$ is the Fourier transform of $u(t, x, y, z)$.

$$\tilde{u}(t, x, y, z) = \int \int \int u(t, x, y, z) e^{-i\omega t}e^{-ikx}e^{-(m+in)y}e^{-(p+q)z} dt dx dy dz =$$
$$= \int \int \int e^{-i\omega t}e^{-ikx}e^{-(m+in)y}e^{-(p+q)z} dt dx dy dz$$

I get that $u(t, x, y, z) = 1$ is the fundamental solution. Is it true? Have I solved the problem correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to compute. What is a fundamental solution for you ? The only definition I know states that $u$ is a fundamental solution of the linear differential operator $A$ when it solves $Au = \delta$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta.